# How to implement simple time interval in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, loops, timer, intervals

I would like to implement a code that calls specific function at specified time intervals i.e. each 5 seconds. Something similar to window.setInterval() method in JavaScript.

There is game_loop() function at the main thread that prints data to STDOUT and waits for keyboard key input from the user. Simplified version of it below:

```
def game_loop
  k = ""
  UI.refresh
  while not k == "q"
    k = UI.read_key # STDIN.getch() is implemented inside of this function
    
    case k
    when "p"
      # do something
    when "f"
      # do something else
    end
  end
end
```

Now I would like to add a code which calls another function at per-defined time interval if condition is met. Example:

```
sleep 5
Production.make if ... # some condition is met
# return to game_loop()
```

I assume this should be done using threads, but I do not have an idea how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this gem:

[rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler)

It would be something like:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.in '5s' do
  Production.make if ... # some condition is met
  game_loop()
end
```